# How to send the authenticated response while authenticating a user via SAML in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, saml-2.0

I have been trying to implement SAML in my application, wherein I want to authenticate the user and create the SAML Token(response) and redirect the user to the other website wherein session gets created.
Till now I have been able to get info on **init** method and **consume** method, which will be implemented by the other website.

```
def init
    request = OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new
    redirect_to(request.create(saml_settings))
  end

  def consume
    response          = OneLogin::RubySaml::Response.new(params[:SAMLResponse])
    response.settings = saml_settings

    if response.is_valid? && user = current_account.users.find_by_email(response.name_id)
      authorize_success(user)
    else
      authorize_failure(user)
    end
  end
```

Following this [Source](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-saml/0.8.1).

I want to create the method which comes in between **init** and **consume**.

**Updated:**

Like I have this one which is I guess is following SAML 1.1, I wanted to know how can I generate a SAML 2.0 request using the get_settings method in Rails.

```
def SSOAccount.get_settings
    settings = Onelogin::Saml::Settings.new    
    settings.issuer                          = "https://example.com/test"    
    settings.idp_sso_target_url                ="https://testexample.com"  
    settings.idp_cert_fingerprint             ="########"
    settings.relying_party_identifier         = "knsdfnsdf"    
    settings.assertion_consumer_service_url   = "https://www.example.com/consume?http_referer=https://testexample.com"
    settings.idp_confirmation_method          = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer"
    settings.asserting_party_id               = "23424dfsdf"            
    settings.referer_url = "https://textexample.com" 
    settings.groups                           = ["USER"]
    settings
  end
```

Comment: What do you mean by the method that comes in between? I created an app so I could play around with saml. The code might help you work out a SAML solution: https://github.com/warwickshire/saml_tools_demo

Comment: The step where I have to authenticate and send the SAML token/response to the other website. Authentication is easy, my main concern is how to formulate the SAML token/response and send. Is there any method in Rails SAML, something, SAML.createResponse which I should use to send the response, or I have to create a normal method which sends the SAML response in XML format? Last question, if I have to send it normally in XML format, is there any specific format which?

Comment: @ReggieB Thanks, I will check the application.

Comment: @ReggieB, I have the IdP metadata now, I am unable to find a methd in the ruby saml gem to parse the metadata to get the settings out of it, as I am using [0.7.3 version( link to 0.7.3 version of gem)](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/releases/tag/0.7.3). Any ideas how can this be done? Plus does this gem support saml 2.0? Because there is no line in the doc which says that which SAML version it supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post the data, but do it in a way that resembles a redirect. The problem with a redirect being that the data is usually larger than can be accommodated in a browser acceptable url.

You need to do it this way so that the post comes from the user's browser rather than your server. That is, the post needs to take the user's browser session with it, so that the associated cookies and session data are submitted with the SAML token.

One solution is to use a self submitting form as shown within [saml_tools_demo's `indentifies#create` view](https://github.com/warwickshire/saml_tools_demo/blob/develop/app/views/identifies/create.html.erb).

Have a look at the [matching controller action](https://github.com/warwickshire/saml_tools_demo/blob/develop/app/controllers/identifies_controller.rb) to see how the data are constructed.

Comment: After seeing the example, the part which I wanted to create is Identities Controller. So the correct sequence is, User clicks on a button to sign in, then the auth request is initiated from the service provider and it goes to identity provider for authentication and the SAML response is created. The response goes to Service provider which takes necessary action based on the response. I hope this is correct.

Comment: I guess I have to create something similar to **create** method in **identities** controller. Is it correct to follow this approach?

Comment: To be honest, if you are unsure what to do - you are going to create something that is vulnerable. I'd recommend you start looking at the SAML docs - this is as good a place to start as any https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0 If you can work through those and understand them, then you can start building a solution. If they don't make any sense, I'd recommend using an off the shelf access management system like https://www.pingidentity.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will refer the github demo and the documentation to start building this.

Comment: Hi @ReggieB, I am going through the [demo app](https://github.com/warwickshire/saml_tools_demo/blob/develop/app/controllers/services_controller.rb) which you have created. I had one doubt, in rails the ruby-saml gem actually creates the xml for us, for example in your example, the request_settings might be giving the Service Provider's xml which is sent to the Identity Provider. I wanted to know that how I can have it generated which is in SAML 2.0 format?

Comment: I have added a code snippet in the updated snippet in my question for reference.

Comment: In the demo app, the SAML documents are generated from templates. For example https://github.com/warwickshire/saml_tools_demo/blob/develop/app/views/identifies/response.saml.erb The templates were based on examples from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0

Comment: Ok, because I was asked to shared the metadata for SP, so I wanted to know how can I generate one? And if I see the previously implemented saml in my project there was a line `redirect_to(request.create(settings))` where settings was taken from a function similar to the one posted in the question above, I could not find a template for it.

Comment: In ruby-saml the SAML documents are generated programatically. For example look at the `create_xml_document` method in https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/blob/master/lib/onelogin/ruby-saml/authrequest.rb It's hard to work out what is being built. That's one of the reasons I used erb templates in saml_tools. Using an erb template makes it easy to read what is being generated, and to create SAML documents based on requirements for alternative services IMO.

Comment: Is there a way to know what is getting generated like printing the xml or can I know the parameters that should be required for this in saml 2.0, based on my above method?

Comment: Hi, I came across one [ruby saml example](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example/blob/master/app/controllers/saml_controller.rb) for generating metadata, but I am using an older version of the gem, is there any method called as `OneLogin::Saml::Metadata.new` in the older version of ruby-saml (0.7.x).

Comment: I have [posted a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204139/how-to-generate-and-share-sp-saml-2-0-metadata-in-rails), and I have almost got the answer but still few things are missing. Can you please take a look at the question and let me know?

Comment: am able to send the authrequest using samltool gem but on the other end, the IDp provider is not able to get the SP ID? How can it be received at the other end

Comment: Thanks a lot @ReggieB, your gem saml-tool saved my day, as I could not update ruby-saml to latest version cuz of app using older ruby version. Now your gem has solved all of my problems.