# How to generate and share SP SAML 2.0 metadata in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, saml-2.0

I have this one which is I guess is following SAML 1.1, I wanted to know how can I generate a new SP metadata using SAML 2.0 in Rails and share with other users, which will help other team in configuring SAML at IDp(Identity Provider end)?

```
require 'onelogin/saml'
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    def get_settings
        settings = Onelogin::Saml::Settings.new    
        settings.issuer                          = "https://example.com/test"    
        settings.idp_sso_target_url                ="https://testexample.com"  
        settings.idp_cert_fingerprint             ="########"
        settings.relying_party_identifier         = "knsdfnsdf"    
        settings.assertion_consumer_service_url   = "https://www.example.com/consume?http_referer=https://testexample.com"
        settings.idp_confirmation_method          = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer"
        settings.asserting_party_id               = "23424dfsdf"            
        settings.referer_url = "https://textexample.com" 
        settings.groups                           = ["USER"]
        return settings, Onelogin::Saml::Metadata.new
      end
   end
     def saml_metadata
         settings, meta = Account.get_settings
         render :xml => meta.generate(settings)
      end
```

Is there any way by which I can generate it and share it with the IDp to configure SAML process.

**Update:**

I am able to get the metadata using the above code now. I just want to be sure that it is SAML 2.0. How can I tell that?

The xml that I get from the above code:

```
  <md:EntityDescriptor entityID="https://example.com/test">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="true">
     <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://www.example.com/consume?http_referer=https://testexample.com" isDefault="true" index="0"/>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
   </md:EntityDescriptor>
```

> Plese note: the above code will only work if you are using [ruby-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml)
>   version 0.7.x, as there is a syntax change from 0.8.x onwards.

Comment: You can try this link to generate SAML2.0 metadata quickly, https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php

Comment: What is entity ID in the form?

Comment: EntityID is an unique identifier for SP or IdP entity. It must be an absolute URL, where it can exactly identify the SAML provider as a resource. Check more about this here, https://spaces.internet2.edu/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/19072376

Comment: I have [ruby-saml gem](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml) in my app, where the new request is created using: `Onelogin::Saml::Authrequest.new`, where as if I go to the documentation it says: `Onelogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new`. I was trying to generate the metadata using the [ruby-saml example](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example/blob/master/app/controllers/saml_controller.rb), but couldn't because of the code difference. Both the gems are same but still there's a code difference because of which I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Can you please check my updated question and help me out?

Comment: Since you are generating SAML2.0 metadata, it is wise to follow SAMLV2.0 metadata spec - https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/51890/SAML%20MD%20simplified%20overview.pdf.     Generally attributes with values namely EntityID, Attribute Consume Service Endpoint, Single Logout Service Endpoint, its public X.509 cert and NameId Format are required.

Comment: @Zeigeist, how can I add requested attributes in the metadata using the ruby code?

Comment: You can't request attributes in metadata, you need to request attributes in SAML AuthnRequest when sending request to IdP from SP.